# Windows 10以降で画面の一部だけブルーライトカットする方法

Tags: windows, winapi

[f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/)というブルーライトカットアプリを使用しているのですが、forumが長期間止まっており、更新も2021年で停止しているため自分で改良版を作れないか考えています。
指定したアプリを起動するとブルーライトカット（正確には色温度設定）をOFFにする機能があるのですが、例として画像編集ソフトや漫画ビューワを開いた時にそのアプリだけでなく画面全体のブルーライトカットがOFFになってしまいまぶしいという問題があるため、そのアプリだけ（画面の一部だけ）ブルーライトカットしたいと思ってます（あるいはブラウザでpixivやYouTubeを開いた時だけブルーライトカットをOFFにするなど）。

以下のページを見ると画面全体の色温度を変更する方法はあるようですが、一部だけ変更することはできないようです。また、紹介されてる[SetDeviceGammaRamp](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setdevicegammaramp)は現在非推奨のようです。
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65641362/3809427

---

追記：漫画ビューワ以外のアプリの例を追加

Answer (score 1):

> 漫画ビューワを開いた時にそのアプリだけでなく画面全体のブルーライトカットがOFFに

[Output Protection Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/medfound/output-protection-manager)などコンテンツ保護機構が作動すると他のプログラムからは関与できなくなるはずです。加えて、このコンテンツ保護機構はウィンドウ単位ではなく出力全体でしょうから、件のブルーライトカットも作動しないのかと思われます。

他の方から有効な解決策が提示されるかもしれませんが、そうでない場合は、独自に制御することは諦めて、素直にOS標準のナイトライトを使用されることをお勧めします。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。漫画ビューワ以外にもブルーライトカットをOFFにしたいアプリがあるため追記しました。また、f.luxでは設定しない限り漫画ビューワを開いたときでもブルーライトカットの状態が続いていました。

Comment: @lamrongol 私は漫画ビューワなどで動作しない原因の一例を挙げました。それに対するコメントおよび質問の追記の意図がよくわかりませんでした。「ブルーライトカットがOFFになってしまいまぶしいという問題」は完全に解決しなくてもよく、「制御が成功するソフトを増やしたい」ということでしょうか？ そうならば制御できていないソフト名を具体的に列挙すべきです。そうでなく「ブルーライトカットがOFFになってしまいまぶしいという問題」を完全に解決したいのなら、私の反例で十分では？

Comment: コメントの意図は:おっしゃる通りせめて「コンテンツ保護機構」が働かないソフトウェアだけでも実現したいということと、f.luxでは「コンテンツ保護機構」が働いてるはずのソフトウェアでもブルーライトカット（色温度設定）が働いていたのでそうしたソフトウェアに対してもブルーライトカットの切り替えができるのではないかということです。